# Saving an animation instance for later use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, lottie

I'm trying to save a Lottie object with methods for later use (another useEffect) into the state, but the state says it's null.

I would like to use the anim.playSegments method specified in the documentation.

Lottie [documentation](http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/web?id=usage).

> Update #1: Tried including anim into the dependency array and event listener for checking if the animation has loaded, but that didn't help and the application resulted in a cycle.
>
> > Animation now loads indefinitely

> **Update #2**: Declared a variable outside of the useEffect and defined it inside of it. Got rid of the state approach. Anim is still null.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useColorMode } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import lottie from 'lottie-web';
import animationData from '../assets/json/sun-to-night'

const ColorMode = () => {
  const container = useRef(null)
  const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode()

  // Segments of the animation
  const midToEnd = [14, 28]
  const startToMid = [0, 14]

  let anim = null

  useEffect(() => {
    anim = lottie.loadAnimation({
      container: container.current,
      animationData: animationData,
      autoplay: false,
      loop: false,
      name: 'anim'
    })

    // Here the animation instance exists and animation is played
    console.log(`${anim}`)
    anim.playSegments(
      (colorMode === 'dark'
        ? startToMid
        : midToEnd), true
    )
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    //anim is null in here and the React app throws an error
    anim.addEventListener('DOMLoaded', () => {
      anim.playSegments(
        (colorMode === 'dark'
          ? startToMid
          : midToEnd), true
      )
    })
  }, [colorMode])


  return (
    <>
      <div>
          ref={container}
          onClick={toggleColorMode}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default ColorMode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using lottie's built-in method "getRegisteredAnimations" in the second useEffect hook and parsing the first element of the array which was my animation.

Then I stored it into a variable which I could manipulate my animation with.
It's a bit of a workaround, but it works. If anyone has a better approach, don't hesitate to share.

Here is the final code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useColorMode } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import lottie from 'lottie-web';
import animationData from '../assets/json/sun-to-night'

const ColorMode = () => {
  const container = useRef(null)
  const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode()

  // Segments of the animation
  const midToEnd = [14, 28]
  const startToMid = [0, 14]

  let anim = null

  useEffect(() => {
    anim = lottie.loadAnimation({
      container: container.current,
      animationData: animationData,
      autoplay: false,
      loop: false,
      name: 'anim'
    })
    // This bit worked from the beginning
    anim.playSegments(
      (colorMode === 'dark'
        ? startToMid
        : midToEnd), true
    )
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    anim = lottie.getRegisteredAnimations()[0]
    //anim no longer throws null
    anim.playSegments(
      (colorMode === 'dark'
        ? startToMid
        : midToEnd), true
    )
  }, [colorMode])

  return (
    <>
      <div>
          ref={container}
          onClick={toggleColorMode}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default ColorMode;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait until your lottie is loaded. You can do this by listening for the `DOMLoaded` event:

```
 const anim = lottie.loadAnimation({
        container: container.current,
        animationData: animationData,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: false,
        name: 'anim'
      });

anim.addEventListener('DOMLoaded', () => {
  anim.playSegments(
        (colorMode === 'dark'
          ? startToMid
          : midToEnd), true
      )
});
```

More here:
https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web#events

Comment: Hello @sam-osb, I'm now waiting for the event, but it doesn't resolve my issue. The lottie animation is loaded, but its methods can't be accessed from the state.

Comment: Could you please share how you're accessing them from the state?

Comment: I'm using the useState hook from React, where I use a method called setAnim to set the state and then anim to call it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be saved to state. My goal is to first load the animation and then use its methods elsewhere - in the second useEffect hook.